# Net id plugin using saml in asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing an application where I have to provide authentication and authorization to users using net id card.

I have installed Net ID from below link:

[Download Net Id from here](http://www.e-identitet.se/index.php?page=net_id_download)

When, I am injecting that Net Id card to my machine via card reader, say I have hosted a site at any particular domain e.g; www.netidtestdomain.com

whenever a user came across to hit that url it should popup an authentication screen which would authenticate that user via any PIN code.

What I have tried is, I visited this site:
[Plugins to login or logout users using Net ID](https://service.secmaker.com/examples/codesnippets.aspx)

But nothing work, I have developed an API in asp.net core 2 and for login once I am able to show the plugin or anything else using the user's own Net Id card then I can get further authorization mapping with the rest of my application flow to authenticate users via Net Id and SAML 2.0 in that core application.
Could any one experience this kind of authentication if so please share your feedbacks if that could useful to try for its solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not being prompted to provide their card, then this is because your web server is not configured properly. It has nothing to do with the html or c# code really. You need to accept and/or require client certs. If you are using IIS, you can use the instructions here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732116.aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication

If you are struggling with auth, I suggest investigating Thinktecture's IdentityServer. That's what we used to implement our authentication via smart card and there's a broad community around it.